# Accessing elements in Simplexml with complex structure

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

I'm new to woking with XML with PHP. I have a fairly complex XML structure and am using simplexml in laravel and am having trouble accessing all the elements I need to get. I am able to loop through the large XML file but simpleXML is returning two objects per record and I only seem to be able to access the elements in 'header', the first object returned...

here is part of the xml object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [identifier] => RCM0635
    [datestamp] => 2015-06-09
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [lidoWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [lido] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [lidoRecID] => RCM:1748
                [descriptiveMetadata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [objectClassificationWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [objectWorkTypeWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [objectWorkType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [term] => musical instruments
                                            )

                                    )

                                [classificationWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [classification] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [term] => Cornet
                                                    )

                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [conceptID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [type] => SH_Class
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

With the code below I can get the elements in the header but I can't figure out how to get the other elements?

```
    $streamer = \Prewk\XmlStringStreamer::createStringWalkerParser(public_path().'/xml/many_mimo_records.xml');


                while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {

                    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);

                    echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->identifier;
                    echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->datestamp;

                }
```

I'd be very grateful for any advice...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand You but in major:

1. You act on `while ($node = $streamer->getNode())` loop what means that after first iteration You'll get this object:

`SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [identifier] => RCM0635
        [datestamp] => 2015-06-09
    )`

so for the first time it's ok to read it like:

`
    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);
    echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->identifier;
    echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->datestamp;

`

but in the second iteration You have:

`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [lidoWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [lido] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [lidoRecID] => RCM:1748
                [descriptiveMetadata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [objectClassificationWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [objectWorkTypeWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [objectWorkType] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [term] => musical instruments
                                            )

                                    )

                                [classificationWrap] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [classification] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [term] => Cornet
                                                    )

                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [conceptID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                            (
                                                                [@attributes] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [type] => SH_Class
                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

`

so the code inside while is wrong.

i sugest to try something like this:

`

```
while ($node = $streamer->getNode()) {

    $simpleXmlNode = simplexml_load_string($node);

    if (!empty($simpleXmlNode->identifier))
        echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->identifier;
    if (!empty($simpleXmlNode->datestamp))
        echo (string)$simpleXmlNode->datestamp;
    if (!empty($simpleXmlNode->lidoWrap)) {
        $lido = $simpleXmlNode->lidoWrap->lido;
        echo (string)$lido->lidoRecID;
        // and so on as the recursive XML node objects
    }
}
```

`